# Get pixel coordinates of cursor in PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, pixels

How can I see the page-relative pixel coordinates (x,y) of the cursor while viewing a PDF?  A solution  for Windows, OS X, or Ubuntu is fine.

I know this can be done in Photoshop, but I don't own Photoshop, so I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PDF readers specifically.

However a couple of general solutions:

Windows: autohotkey has tools for pulling window relative coordinates so one just needs to negate toolbars etc.

Linux: On X11 systems a tool called Xev is available that displays all X11 events including cursor movement and it can be told to be limited to a particular window ID gained via xwininfo.

Comment: I guess the problem with those solutions is that it is not very robust. If I write a tool to help extract that info, other people would need the same settings as me to use it.

Comment: Depends, without knowing more of exactly what you want the data for?

Comment: I have several PDFs that are just image scans of forms. I have all the data necessary to auto-complete the forms, but I need to first find the pixel location of each field so that my autocomplete app knows where to write the data. Right now, it's just trial and error which is slow and tedious.

Comment: Are the fields are identical rectangle boxes other than the content in them?

Comment: No, they're scattered all over the place and of varying sizes and shapes. Imagine a really long health insurance form. Hence, I need a tool to help me quickly identify and write down the bounding areas of each field.

Answer (score 0):

A pdf (and ps) viewer that shows cursor coordinates is gsview, but it only runs in windows. So far as I know it is the only one that does that.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include a download link and a screenshot of the relevant feature?

Comment: for posterity: https://www.ghostscript.com/download.html